# ODE Runge Kutta MATLAB error

Tags: matlab, ode, runge-kutta

so I'm trying to create a Runge Kutta function and this is my code :

```
function [t,U] = RK(f, n, eta, interv)
h = (interv(2)-interv(1))/n;
t = interv(1):h:interv(2);

v(1) = eta(1);
w(1) = eta(2);
for i=1:n
    k1 = f([v(i),w(i)]);
    k2 = f([v(i),w(i)]+h*k1/2); %f(t(i)+h/2, u(:,i)+h*k1/2);
    k3 = f([v(i),w(i)]+h*k2/2);
    k4 = f([v(i),w(i)]+h*k3);

    v(i+1) = v(i) + h*(k1(1)+2*k2(1)+2*k3(1)+k4(1))/6;
    w(i+1) = w(i) + h*(k1(2)+2*k2(2)+2*k3(2)+k4(2))/6;
end
U = [v;w];
end
```

Where U is a matrix of 2 lines and n+1 columns, here is the problem when I try to execute this function, for example :

```
RK(sin, 10, [0,1], [5,15])
```

I get the error `not enough input arguments` but when I try to execute the code as a script and replacing f by sin every thing works and i get the U matrix
Can someon tell what is the solution ?

Comment: You're trying to use the sin as an anonymous function. I dont have any experience with this, but SO is littered with info about that.

Comment: thank you A. Visser I had just to add the @ to the RK(@sin,....)

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `sin` as a function handle. Just add the `@` symbol and you're set.

```
RK(@sin, 10, [0,1], [5,15])
```