# Questions about slicesample in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

My question is about `slicesample` in Matlab. It is divided into 2 parts:

1) The structure of slice sampling:
Suppose this is the density function

```
function den=f(param)
den=mvnpdf(param);
end
```

and this is my attemp for the main function

```
N = 3;
param = slicesample([1 2 3 4 5 6 7],N,'pdf',f);
```

It tells me `Error using f (line 2) Not enough input arguments.`
Where is the error?

2) The `3` points that are included in `param` are `3` random draws of `param` from `f`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ODE Runge Kutta MATLAB error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169143/ode-runge-kutta-matlab-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@` before `f` so the command should be

```
param = slicesample([1 2 3 4 5 6 7], N, 'pdf', @f);
```

This is detailed in the documentation for [`slicesample`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/slicesample.html).

The results of `slicesample` are 3 random samples from the distribution given by `f` for each of the initial samples in `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`. So the output for me in one run is

```
param = slicesample([1 2 3 4 5 6 7], N, 'pdf', @f)
param =

    0.9519    4.5174    2.8350    2.0869    4.3373    6.0897    7.0216
    2.5261    4.8106    3.1633    3.1249    1.8355    5.4323    6.1954
    2.0635    5.7164    2.1639    2.6342    1.6730    5.5212    6.0935
```

and in another is

```
>> param = slicesample([1 2 3 4 5 6 7], N, 'pdf', @f)
param =

    0.2897    3.2341    2.9016    4.3718    3.7444    4.9612    7.3525
    0.3242    4.7909    1.4022    3.0182    5.1264    2.6466    6.5270
    1.6639    5.5771    0.4790    3.3013    2.6992    2.3913    6.5019
```